# Tools to track my coding progress in Ruby

Tags: ruby, issue-tracking

In a nutshell, I'm looking for tools for tracking my progress in "fleshing-out" a complex system in Ruby.

Usually when I start working on a new system in Ruby, I first write an `outline.rb` file that contains `stub` class definitions for all the classes I think I'll want to use.  Then I gradually implement the functionality.

Are there any tools out there for quickly surveying my `stubs` and keeping track of which ones still need to be implemented, and how long each implementation took me, in hours?

Answer (score 5):

I usually track my progress through my tests. For example, if you're doing TDD/BDD, you could use rspec and create tests that are marked as "pending"-tests without a body basically.

Take this gist for example (https://gist.github.com/4150506)

```
describe "My API" do

  it "should return a list of cities (e.g. New York, Berlin)"
  it "should return a list of course categories"
  it "should return a list of courses based on a given city"
  it "should return a list of courses based on a category and city"

end
```

In it, I list a few tests that I expect the system to pass once all the implementation details are in place. This allows me to get an overall view of what I'm building without getting too deep too quickly.

Update: The idea is to be able to run the specs at the command line and rspec will tell you which tests are passing, failing or pending.

As for the time tracking part, I just use a timer app (tickspot.com for example). You can always make note of the timestamps on your spec files too to get a sense of when you started modifying the files and when you stopped.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is essentially "no".

How do you define "done"? Not "just a stub", or exhibiting complete behavior? How do you define "complete" behavior? What about methods you didn't stub originally, of which I can only imagine there would be dozens, if not hundreds.

Time against stubbed methods doesn't strike me as a meaningful statistic, rather time against functionality. This should be handled by issue tracking tickets and commit logs, but that will reflect overall time, not specifically time on task, which is often significantly different.

I don't see how this can be done with any real accuracy over a project of any significant size without very granular issue tracking, time entry, and unit and behavioral tests. Even then, you'd likely need to build out some tools to help with your particular methodology.